# Recording time of a program

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, time, pthreads

So I'm working on a c assignment that generates an array, and uses threads to determine different characteristics.

At the end of the program I need to print the wall time, the user time, and the system time. I thought I did this correctly but my results seem to point otherwise.

After multiple tests, The user time is almost always 0 and the system time is always 0. I know the user time should be greater than the wall time since it's multithreaded code.

Here's how I'm calculating it, if anyone could point out my mistake or explain why its getting an incorrect time then that'd be great:

EDIT: issue was irrelevant with code. (something else was wrong in my threads)
thanks

Comment: struct timeval dif = finish; You are assigning to dif. But you are accessing the diff. I think this is the fault you made.

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S that was just a typo from copying over. fixed in edit

Comment: Could you add your code part related to this functionality with your query? with our seeing your code our assumption are rather vague.

Answer (score 0):

System time should almost definitely be zero, I wouldn't expect much time to be spent in kernel-mode.  As for User Time being zero, it is possible that all operations are taking less than one [CPU tick](https://superuser.com/questions/101183/what-is-a-cpu-tick).  If you are trying to time a short lived operation (for example, one call to `malloc` or something), then I would definitely expect the time to be zero.

Comment: The code has a lot more operations than that. It involves making multiple threads to iterate over a large array and compute the sum or max. So I feel as if the time should be different

Comment: Are you calculating time for each thread, or after all threads complete?

Comment: i only have what I have above. I calculate before everything, do everything with my threads, and then calculate the difference once everything done